# Expresiones lambda - suma

Tags: .net, lambda

estoy trabajando con expresiones lambda pero tengo un problema
tengo este metodo:

```
public static void Test_LambdaExpresions()
    {
        var albums = new List<Album>
        {
            new Album { Quantity = 10, Artist = "Betontod", Title = "Revolution" },
            new Album { Quantity = 50, Artist = "The Dangerous Summer", Title = "The Dangerous Summer" },
            new Album { Quantity = 200, Artist = "Depeche Mode", Title = "Spirit" },
            new Album { Quantity = 300, Artist = "Depeche Mode", Title = "other" },
            new Album { Quantity = 300, Artist = "Depeche Mode", Title = "Spirit" },
        };

        //left
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Album), "album");
        var comparison = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Property(parameter, Type.GetType("Test_LambdaExpresions.Album").GetProperty("Quantity")), Expression.Constant(100));
        Expression<Func<Album, bool>> expCo = null;
        expCo = Expression.Lambda<Func<Album, bool>>(comparison, parameter);



        //rigth
        var parameter2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Album), "album");
        var comparison2 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, Type.GetType("Test_LambdaExpresions.Album").GetProperty("Title")), Expression.Constant("Spirit"));
        Expression<Func<Album, bool>> expCo2 = null;
        expCo2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Album, bool>>(comparison2, parameter2);

        Expression<Func<Album, bool>> finalExpression = Expresions<Album>.AndAlso(expCo, expCo2);

        Console.WriteLine(finalExpression.Body.ToString());
        var discountedAlbums = albums.Where(finalExpression.Compile());
    }
```

con esto al final tengo una condicion de este tipo:

> ((album.Quantity > 100) AndAlso (album.Title == "Spirit"))

pero necesito sumar ahora un valor constante a la cantidad, para obtener un where del estilo:

> ((album.Quantity + 10 > 100) AndAlso (album.Title == "Spirit"))

Como puedo hacer esto?, este pues es un ejemplo sencillo lo que realmente necesito lograr es a un campo de tipo fecha adicionarle unos minutos y compararlo con otra fecha, pero quería comenzar con algo mas simple ¿esto es posible?, de antemano gracias

Answer (score 2):

Encontré una solución para el tema específico de las fechas que necesitaba, la tome de este ejemplo: https://github.com/vc3/ExoModel/blob/master/ExoModel/ModelExpression.cs

con esto obtengo un where del estilo:

> album => ((album.dateCreation.AddMinutes(30) > 25/09/2018 18:15:29) AndAlso (album.Title == "Spirit"))

```
        public static Expression AddOffset(string unit, double offset, Expression date)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case "year":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddYears"), Expression.Constant((int)offset));
            case "month":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddMonths"), Expression.Constant((int)offset));
            case "week":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddDays"), Expression.Constant(offset * 7));
            case "day":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddDays"), Expression.Constant(offset));
            case "hour":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddHours"), Expression.Constant(offset));
            case "minute":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddMinutes"), Expression.Constant(offset));
            case "second":
                return Expression.Call(date, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("AddSeconds"), Expression.Constant(offset));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

ese método lo uso de la siguiente manera:

```
            var parameter3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Album), "album");
        var param = Expression.Property(parameter, Type.GetType("Test_LambdaExpresions.Album").GetProperty("dateCreation"));
        Expression<Func<Album, bool>> expCo3 = null;


        Expression addMinutesDateExp = AddOffset("minute", 30, param);

        var comparison3 = Expression.GreaterThan(addMinutesDateExp, Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now));
        Console.WriteLine(addMinutesDateExp.ToString());
        expCo3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Album, bool>>(comparison3, parameter3);

        Expression<Func<Album, bool>> finalExpression2 = Expresions<Album>.AndAlso(expCo3, expCo2);
```